# Replace a character of specified column

Tags: shell, awk

I am editing a file in which I have to replace hyphen of a column 2 with space. I tried using gsub but unable come out with result

```
awk '{gsub(/\"|\-/,"",$2)}1' events
```

Input file

```
xxxxx 2019-04-03 19:40:51.310 1.7615 31.1994 10
xxxxx 2019-04-02 01:22:48.140 -7.2965 114.5721 35
xxxxx 2019-04-01 23:05:28.610 -7.2121 114.537 21
```

expected results should be

```
xxxxx 2019 04 03 19:40:51.310 1.7615 31.1994 10
xxxxx 2019 04 02 01:22:48.140 -7.2965 114.5721 35
xxxxx 2019 04 01 23:05:28.610 -7.2121 114.537 21
```

Comment: Replace the `""` (empty) with an actual space `" "` and it works. Also, no need to escape the hyphen or the quotes. But you can't remove the quotes and replace hyphen with a space in the same `gsub`, you need separate commands for that one, like: `awk '{gsub(/-/," ",$2);gsub(/"/,"",$2)}1' file`

Comment: @anubhava The date is missing the hyphens. That is where it is different.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the following `awk` command, where you substitute all `-` only in the 2nd field by spaces

```
echo 'xxxxx 2019-04-02 01:22:48.140 -7.2965 114.5721 35' | awk '{gsub(/-/," ",$2);print }'
xxxxx 2019 04 02 01:22:48.140 -7.2965 114.5721 35
```

Then just run it on the whole file.

```
awk '{gsub(/-/," ",$2)} 1' events
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following, specifically written and tested  for provided samples(considering that you have dashes only in 2nd field as per shown samples) with `sed`.

```
sed  's/\([^ ]*\) \([^-]*\)-\([^-]*\)-\([^-]*\)\(.*\)/\1 \2 \3 \4 \5/' Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
xxxxx 2019 04 03 19:40:51.310 1.7615 31.1994 10 
xxxxx 2019 04 02 01:22:48.140  -7.2965 114.5721 35
xxxxx 2019 04 01 23:05:28.610  -7.2121 114.537 21
```

Comment: Sorry buddy but your commands are removing the `-` in the second part of the line (with the numerical values) `-7.2965` should remain as-is

Comment: @Allan, Thanks a TON buddy for letting know fully missed it, I am sticking to only my `sed` solution, will try to add some other `awk` too, thanks a TON again buddy. cheers.

Comment: Look at my awk solution ;-)

Comment: Anyway nice sed solution as well!

Comment: @Allan, I know(its nice, ++ ve) I thought it too, but was trying to do with a different way too,since James sir already posted it in comments so thought lets do with another approach :)

Answer (score 0):

A simple sed that works for this case:

```
 sed 's/\([0-9]\{4\}\)-\([0-9]\{2\}\)-\([0-9]\{2\}\)/\1 \2 \3/' file
```